# Canonical list of Dragon Age novels

Tags: dragon-age-series

Does Dragon age have a canonical list of novels I can read? And are they available **online**?

Comment: Hi ShrimpFan, have you looked into this yourself yet? I think you can find an answer really easily by searching online for the exact same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five published novels:

- [Dragon Age: The Stolen Throne](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Age:_The_Stolen_Throne)
- [Dragon Age: The Calling](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Age:_The_Calling)
- [Dragon Age: Asunder](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Asunder)
- [Dragon Age: The Masked Empire](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Age:_The_Masked_Empire)
- [Dragon Age: Last Flight](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Last_Flight)

The first three novels were written by David Gaider, lead writer for the *Dragon Age series* at the time, while the fourth one was written by Patrick Weekes, writer for *Dragon Age: Inquisition* and current lead writer of the series, and the fifth one by Liane Merciel.

There is also an anthology of short stories: [Dragon Age: Tevinter Nights](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Tevinter_Nights).

Source, [here](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Age#Novels).